# Override SQL Server Maxrecursion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have a table with a structure like

```
name    properties
x       thing1, thing2, thing3
y       otherthing1, otherthing2, otherthing3
```

and I would like to map this to a one to many relationship like

```
name  properties
x     thing1
x     thing2
x     thing3
```

This following solution I have works, but runs up against the Maxrecursion option in SQL Server

```
;with tmp(brandName, drugList, genericName) as (
select brandName, LEFT(genericName, CHARINDEX(',',genericName+',')-1),
    STUFF(genericName, 1, CHARINDEX(',',genericName+','), '')
from eeeee
where LEN(genericName) - LEN(replace(genericName,',','')) < 100
union all
select brandName, LEFT(genericName, CHARINDEX(',',genericName+',')-1),
    STUFF(genericName, 1, CHARINDEX(',',genericName+','), '')
from tmp
where genericName > ''
)
select brandName,  drugList
from tmp
order by brandName
```

the where clause is what let's this query run, because there are some rows in the multi-valued column that have over 100 items in the list.  Is there any way to sneak around and override SQL Server's 100 max limit on recursion?  Or will it be best to just go ahead and split the columns that have over 100 values into two and then do the recursion?

Comment: use a [query hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181714.aspx) at the end like `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: I tried option (maxrecursion 100), obviously I did not understand how to implement this.  +1

Comment: `(MAXRECURSION 100)` is the default value. `(MAXRECURSION 0)` overrides the maximum recursion to no limit. Per MSDN: `Specifies the maximum number of recursions allowed for this query. number is a nonnegative integer between 0 and 32767. When 0 is specified, no limit is applied. If this option is not specified, the default limit for the server is 100.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest more efficient solution without using recursion -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      name NVARCHAR(50)
    , properties NVARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (name, properties)
VALUES 
    ('x', 'thing1, thing2, thing3'),
    ('y', 'otherthing1, otherthing2, otherthing3')

SELECT  
      data.name
    , property = LTRIM(data.property)
FROM (
    SELECT 
          name = p.value('(./n)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
        , property = p.value('(./s)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)')
    FROM (
        SELECT field = CAST('<r><s>' + REPLACE(t.properties + ',', ',', '</s><n>' + t.name + '</n></r><r><s>') + '</s></r>' AS XML) 
        FROM @temp t
    ) d
    CROSS APPLY field.nodes('/r') t(p)
) data
WHERE data.name IS NOT NULL
```

---

Yes, of course. Each string in table has a fixed separator char. We replace separator char to part of XML structure. We get lines like this:

```
thing1, thing2, thing3 -> <r><s>thing1</s><s>thing2</s><s>thing3</s></r>
```

Convert string to XML date type and parse formed tree:

```
<r>
 <s>thing1</s>
 <n>x</n>
</r>
<r>
 <s> thing2</s>
 <n>x</n>
</r>
<r>
 <s> thing3</s>
 <n>x</n>
</r>
```

Comment: this is pretty interesting.  care to explain how it works?  i've not seen anything like this before

Comment: Just now getting back to this answer where you explained how it works.  Thanks!